# Repeat last action in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In Microsoft Word I can repeat the last action by pressing F4.
Is there a way to repeat the last action in Notepad++?

Specifically what I'm looking to do is that I select some text in a document manually (which I want to keep doing) and then I now have to go to TextFX -> TextFX Characters -> Proper Case.

I want to be able to select the text and then press F4 or some other key to format the selected text to Proper Case.

Is that possible?

I don't want the entire document to be Proper Case, so a Macro is out of the question I think.

Comment: Have you try Crtl+Y

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to redo something I already did (my question is not an undo-redo question), I'm trying to repeat the same action I just performed.

Comment: This may not be the ideal scenario, but perhaps you could use something like [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) or [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to create a script to execute the menu clicks and bind it to a global hotkey. I realize this is overkill, but it's an idea...

Answer (score 1):

Action you request isn't currently available.

This is not a perfect answer, but there is a workaround: for most actions, you can use macro-recording feature. See items of **Macro** menu.

For advanced text editing or editor control, use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) as suggested by commenter above.

Comment: That, or Clavier+ (here: http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=fr). Fantastic little freeware, very easy to use.